# vue js v-for input type with v-model

Tags: vue.js

I want two input field with name1 and name2, name1 = Peter, name2= Kitty. But i have not any idea to handle it.

```
<div v-for="list in item">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" v-model="name"></>
    {{list.name}}
</div>

data() {
    return {
        item: [{ name: 'Peter' },{ name: 'Kitty' }],
        name: ''
    }
}
```

here i want:

input type="text" id="name1" name="name2" v-model="name1"><--Show Peter

input type="text" id="name1" name="name2" v-model="name2"><--Show Kitty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `v-model`. You need to bind it to the name attribute of the object in your `item` array.

Change `v-model="name"` to `v-model="list.name"`

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/479343/)

Comment: got =`name-${index}` name="name" v-model="list.name" />

Comment: i found my way with :id="'name'+index"

Comment: Hi, @T. Dirks I had another question. How could I use `@input` regular expression to check my value and replace model value? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple input elements you want to display, you should also have multiple slots of where you will put the data. For example, you could do it like this, by adding a `value` property to the item element:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      { name: 'Peter', value: '' },
      { name: 'Kitty', value: '' }
    ],
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <label>{{item.name}}:</label>
    <input type="text" name="item.name" v-model="item.value">
  </div>

  <!-- Output for debugging purposes -->
  {{items}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div v-for="list in item">
    <input type="text" v-model="list.name"></>
    {{list.name}}
</div>

data() {
    return {
        item: [{ name: 'Peter' },{ name: 'Kitty' }],
        name: ''
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeW its self explaining

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="list in item" :key="list.id">
    <input type="text" :id="list.name" :name="list.name" :v-model="list.name"/>
    {{ list.name }}
</div>
```